# Ruby delete_if an array subset

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array, and I want to perform a `delete_if` on a subset (any n items) of that array (and it modifies the array in memory)

With the full array I can do

```
array.delete_if do |item|
  should_be_deleted?(item)
end
```

If I want to restrict to the first n items, the following won't work

```
array.take(n).delete_if do |item|
  should_be_deleted?(item)
end
```

As it will create a new array and perform the `delete_if` on that new array

Is there an alternative, like a `take_and_delete_if` that would delete only the first n items (if the block returns true for each) ?

## EDIT :

I want to process from  array `a` and `b`, `c` by chunks of 3 (and delete from the array after performing the operation)

```
by_batch_of(3, until: (proc { a.empty? })) do 
  # This sets an instance variable @by = 3, and will iterate as long as `a` has any item
  process_from_a # Will move @by items in a to either array b or c or fail
  process_from_b # Will move @by items in b to c or fail
  process_from_c # Should move items or fail and put back in a
end
```

Sample processing method

```
process_from_a(by: @by)
  a.take_and_delete_if(by: by) do |item| # The +take_and_delete_if+ methods is the one I need
  b << item if reason1
  c << item if reason2
  reason1 or reason2 # Delete if the item was moved away
end
```

Performance is what I am looking for

Example

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = []
c = []
```

1st batch of 3

- process_from_a(by: 3)

  ```
  a = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9] # 3 failed so delete_if returned false, it remains in the array (order doesn't matter)
  b = [1] # 1 moved to b
  c = [2] # 2 moved to c
  ```
- process_from_b

  ```
  a = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  b = []
  c = [1,2] # 2 moved to c
  ```
- process_from_c

  ```
  a = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1] # 1 was rejected in a
  b = []
  c = [] # 1,2 processed from c
  ```

The next iteration would for example process [3,4,5] from a, etc.

#### Performance

Suppose my array is very big (10k, 100k) and I want process items by batch of 10. I don't want expensive solutions to filter the first 10 items and delete_if the whole array with `index < 10`...

Comment: An example with expected output would be helpful here.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Yes just added that, thanks

Comment: Your example looks like a producer/consumer problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to do an [in place replacement](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) with filtered elements from a subset:

```
a = (0..10000).to_a;
a[0, 100] = a[0, 100].delete_if(&:odd?)
```

A benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("with_index")  { (0..10000).to_a.delete_if.with_index { |k, i| k.odd? && i < 100 } }
  x.report("slice") { a = (0..10000).to_a; a[0, 100] = a[0, 100].delete_if(&:odd?) }

  x.compare!
end
```

Gives these results on MRI Ruby 2.4.0p0:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
          with_index    58.000  i/100ms
               slice   273.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
          with_index    602.354  (± 6.6%) i/s -      3.016k in   5.033200s
               slice      2.775k (±10.0%) i/s -     13.923k in   5.075605s

Comparison:
               slice:     2774.9 i/s
          with_index:      602.4 i/s - 4.61x  slower
```

Comment: Hey, do you have any idea of the performance gain VS other methods ? That sounds like exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a benchmark against the previously suggested version.

Answer (score 1):

The logic might look as follows:

```
array.delete_if do |item|
  next if should_be_skipped?(item)
  should_be_deleted?(item)
end
```

Example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a.delete_if do |item|
  next if item == 2 # would skip 2 because we want so
  item % 2 == 0     # would remove all even numbers (except for 2)
end
#=> [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Just to clarify: answer is rather general, just to show the OP the idea about how such cases might be handled.

## edit

For given case, to skip 4 first elements you'd go with:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a.delete_if.with_index do |item, index|
  index > 3 && item.even?
end
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Comment: _"first n items"_ requires some sort of index.

Comment: @Stefan I think the general solution is better in terms of showing how it could work. Whether it would be based on `index` or on anything else depends on case

Comment: Sure, but how could `should_be_skipped?` determine the item's position?

Comment: @Stefan ok, I'll maybe edit the answer with something indexing

Comment: Hi sorry actually I don't care if it's the first n or any n, just edited. Also the problem with your solution, is that it iterates on the full array. Imagine my array has 10k items and I just want to process by group of 10... that means your condition would be evaluated on 10k objects instead of just 10

Answer (score 1):

may be you need something like this?

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].delete_if.with_index{|e,i| i<3} # => [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

items with indexes in range 0..2 were deleted

Comment: To complete your answer, you should incorporate the `should_be_deleted?(item)` part from the OP's question as well.

Comment: Does the `with_index` method iterate on the whole array to select a subset ? See my comment on the previous answer. I'm dealing with big arrays and I want to avoid looping through all items.

Comment: yep, btw you can use with_index in map, select, each and other enumerators

Answer (score 1):

You can use method [`#shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) to remove first `n` elements, for example:

```
> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 > a.shift(3)
 => [1, 2, 3] 
 > a
 => [4, 5]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to remove the first `n` items only if `should_be_deleted?(item)` for the corresponding item returns `true`.

Comment: @Stefan Exactly. Now What can be done (and that I have implemented in the mean time), is to delete_if the `unshifted` array and put the remnant back in `a`

Answer (score 0):

```
def skip_then_test(arr, nbr_to_skip)
  arr.delete_if { |item| (nbr_to_skip -= 1) < 0 && item.even? }
end

skip_then_test [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 0
  #=> [3, 5, 7] 
skip_then_test [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 1
  #=> [2, 3, 5, 7] 
skip_then_test [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 2
  #=> [2, 3, 5, 7] 
skip_then_test [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3
  #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]

arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  
skip_then_test arr, 4
  #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
arr 
  #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Another way follows.

```
def skip_then_test(arr, nbr_to_skip)
  arr.replace(arr[0, nbr_to_skip] + arr[nbr_to_skip..-1].delete_if(&:even?))
end

arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
skip_then_test arr, 3
  #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7] 
arr
  #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```